# Define JAVA_OPTS in build.sbt in Play Framework 2.3.0 (Java)

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I'm trying to define JAVA_OPTS in build.scala in order to specify the debug port and the configuration file for the run and test tasks, but it doesn't work. I launch `activator` and then `run` or `test`.
Here is my build.sbt :

```
name := "machinchose"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs
)

Keys.fork in run := true

javaOptions in run ++= Seq(
    "-Xdebug",
    "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9997",
    "-Dconfig.file=conf/developpement.conf",
    "-Xms128m",
    "-Xmx1024m"
)

Keys.fork in Test := true

javaOptions in Test ++= Seq(
    "-Xdebug",
    "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9997",
    "-Dconfig.file=conf/test.conf",
    "-Xms128m",
    "-Xmx1024m"
)
```

What did I messed ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Play doesn't really support fork in run; it may just be ignoring that setting. So then your `javaOptions` won't work since there's no new JVM. What you have to do is start activator (or sbt) itself with those options, or set one of the env vars `JAVA_OPTS`, `SBT_OPTS`, or `ACTIVATOR_OPTS`. There's also a `-jvm-debug` to activator to add a debugger.

Comment: I tried this (I wrote a batch file which set JAVA_OPT and launch activator), but by this way, to use `build.sbt` to set javaOptions for the `test` task – as recommended by the documentation – doesn't worked, I fork the Test or not. And `-jvm-debug` doesn't work with Windows (I can't use Linux, alas).

Comment: -jvm-debug is supposed to work on Windows; can you try with activator 1.2.3 (released yesterday) and file an issue on https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues?state=open if it is broken? It's true that the _OPTS env vars won't let you distinguish options for run and tests... I'm not sure how to do that with play.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask Play to start a JPDA debug port when starting the console. You can then connect using Java debugger. Use the play debug command to do that:

$ play debug

When a JPDA port is available, the JVM wil log this line during boot:

Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9999

```
Note: Using play debug the JPDA socket will be opened on port 9999. You can also set the JPDA_PORT environment variable yourself using set JPDA_PORT=1234.
```

Comment: I use Play 2.3.0, `play debug` doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Start Activator with debugging

`activator -jvm-debug 9999`